# I need to search an Object Array I created for a specific user-generated input and return one of the contents of the same element containing the input

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, object

I made a class I named DictionarySample to represent the fact that the procedures within this class are supposed to replicate several similar Dicitionary functionalities

```
public  class DictionarySample
    {
        public int idNumb {get; set;}
        public string fn { get; set; }
        public string ln { get; set; }
        public string adr { get; set; }
        public string bday { get; set; }
        public int num { get; set; }

    }
```

via an array which I have initiated in the form class.

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int lastElementIndex = 0;
        DictionarySample[] database = new DictionarySample[1000];
        PriorityQueueSample[] line = new PriorityQueueSample[1000];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    public void buttonApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool digitCharactersInfirst = textBoxFirstName.Text.Any(char.IsDigit);
        bool digitCharactersInlast = textBoxLastName.Text.Any(char.IsDigit);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxIDNumber.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter an ID Number.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        else if (int.Parse(textBoxIDNumber.Text) < 100000 || int.Parse(textBoxIDNumber.Text) > 999999)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID Number.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxFirstName.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter First Name.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        else if (digitCharactersInfirst == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("First Name can't contain digits. Please re-enter Given Name.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            textBoxFirstName.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxLastName.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Last Name.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        else if (digitCharactersInlast == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Last Name can't contain digits. Please re-enter Surname.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            textBoxLastName.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxAdr.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Address.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxBirthday.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Date of Birth.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        else
        {

            string c = "Proceed with the following Account Information? \n" + textBoxFirstName.Text + " " + textBoxLastName.Text + "," + textBoxIDNumber.Text + "\nAddress: " + textBoxAdr.Text + "\nBirthday: " + textBoxBirthday.Text;


            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(c, "Verify information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                int a = int.Parse(textBoxIDNumber.Text);
                lastElementIndex++;
                DictionarySample d = new DictionarySample();
                d.idNumb = a;
                d.fn = textBoxFirstName.Text;
                d.ln = textBoxLastName.Text;
                d.adr = textBoxAdr.Text;
                d.bday = textBoxBirthday.Text;
                d.num = lastElementIndex;
                database[lastElementIndex] = d;
                textBoxIDNumber.Text = String.Empty;
                textBoxFirstName.Text = String.Empty;
                textBoxLastName.Text = String.Empty;
                textBoxAdr.Text = String.Empty;
                textBoxBirthday.Text = String.Empty;


                string prio = "You may now Line-Up.\nYour priority number is:\t" + lastElementIndex;
                MessageBox.Show(prio, "Take Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {                    
            }
        }
```

The program goes like this: It asks the user for an IDNumber, Name, Address, and Birthday, then internally generates a priority number based on their order of application, which upon the click of the "Apply" button stores the User Info in my array named database.

*Check out a screen capture of form at http://tinypic.com/r/vfgkyh/8

After the user has applied, he then has to input his ID Number in the second panel which upon the click of the Line-Up button must look for the ID Number in the database and return the corresponding priority number, which will then both be inserted into another array with the functionalities of a Priority Queue.

My current code for the click of this Line-Up button goes as follows

```
private void buttonLineUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int temp = int.Parse(textBoxIDLINE.Text);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxIDLINE.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter an ID Number.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        else if (int.Parse(textBoxIDLINE.Text) < 100000 || int.Parse(textBoxIDLINE.Text) > 999999)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID Number.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        else 
        {
            for (int looper = 0; looper < 500; looper++)
            {
                //if (d.idNumb.database[looper] == int.Parse(textBoxIDNumber.Text))
                //{
                //}
                //int idnb = 0;
                //int priorityk = 0;

                foreach (DictionarySample d in database)
                {
                    if (d.idNumb == int.Parse(textBoxIDNumber.Text))
                    {
                        PriorityQueueSample lin = new PriorityQueueSample();
                        lin.idNumber = d.idNumb;
                        lin.pnumb = d.num;

                        labeldisplay.Text = d.idNumb + "," + d.num;
                    }


                }

            }

        }
```

I haven't started inputting the data into the priorityqueue array because I can't access the data from the Database array. Please help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Hi!! How do I access the database and search through the d.idNumb elements for the user input, then return the corresponding d.num?

Comment: Remove all frills and ask you question with pointed code. One of your problems is that everything is one blob of code without any separation of concerns.

Comment: Please don't link to external resources. You can inline images in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If idNumb is unique then instead of:

```
DictionarySample[] database = new DictionarySample[1000];
```

you could use:

```
Dictionary<int, DictionarySample> = new Dictionary<int, DictionarySample>();
```

And then save the idNumb as the key of the dictionary.